# Alignment of book icon in Beamer and text in tiny size

Tags: beamer, icon

I want to use the book item of Beamer and text in `\tiny` size, but the text "My book" in the code below seems to be in subscript. There any way to align the book item and the text (without using `\vspace*{}`)?

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{\tiny {\includegraphics[scale=.75]{beamericonbook}}~My book...}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `adjustbox` package to change the vertical alignment of the image.

If you need more fine control, you could use a `\raisebox{...}{...}` to move the image up or down:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{\tiny {\includegraphics[scale=.75,valign=c]{beamericonbook}}~My book...}


{\tiny {\raisebox{-1.2ex}{\includegraphics[scale=.75]{beamericonbook}}}~My book...}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]